# Linking CSS file from a subfolder

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to link my css file from a subfolder but it seems like it is not being read.
but when I move my css to the same directory as with the index php file, it is being read.
Can you please help me how to solve this problem?

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">sdfdsf</a>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
a{
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvDEg.png)

Comment: perhaps `./css/style.css`

Comment: Please provide the paths of the following, relative to the webroot or site URL:
(1) - Your CSS file   
(2) - Your PHP file   
(3) - The page file (e.g. index) that this relates to

Answer (score 1):

First, try using forward-slash (/) rather than backslash.

However, looking at your screenshot it seems to be a problem with the link being relative.

From the screenshot, you're at `/practice/wallet4/wallet.php` When you include your style on there as `css/style.css` the browser is going to look relative to where you are, so it's going to look in `/practice/wallet4/css/style.css` which might not be where your file is.

You can make an absolute reference by putting a forward slash at the beginning, like `/css/style.css`. This will tell the browser to look in a CSS folder that is next to your practice folder.

It really just depends on how your folders and files are setups. Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: Hello. thank you for your answer. But everything is working fine with my html codes and referencing css file from a subfolder. But when I start recreating my project in "php", that's when my problem starts. By the way, I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. :( Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: where is your `css` folder? Is it in your `practice` folder? => `/practice/css/style.css`, Is it in the `wallet4` folder? => `/practice/wallet4/css/style.css` depends where the `css` folder is

Comment: It's in /practice/wallet4/css/style.css.
But it works now. I move the project folder directly to localhost folder.
localhost/wallet4/css/style.css.
I don't know why I can't reference a CSS file if I put my prof folder to another folder.